# How to add a variable to a varaiable name

Tags: python

I have Python code that is trying to get the position of a player. However, I always get an error ('cave_' is not defined).

My (error causing)code looks like:

```
player_pos = cave_(player_pos)[n] #n is a number
```

The `cave` and `player_pos` variables have been defined and `player_pos` is a tuple. I expect `player_pos` to be updated so that its value is something like '5'.

The entire snippet of code looks like:

```
    global player_pos
    cave_0 = (1,4,0,0)
    cave_1 = (2,11,2,0)
```

and so on 11 times. Then the offending block of code.

How can this be debugged?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: What error are you getting? what is `cave_`? please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @DeepSpace - The op is trying to access a variable dynamically (i.e `cave_1`). Most likely, an xy problem

Comment: Well, the first step in debugging is reading the error and traceback, but you haven't provided either of those.

Comment: You shouldn't be using variables like this. Make `cave` a dictionary of tuples or tuple of tuples, so you can do something like  `cave[player_pos][n]`

Comment: Appears to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for what you are trying to do.  Consider this statement:

```
player_pos = cave_(player_pos)[n]
```

First, this will call a function `cave_()` with the argument `player_pos`.  Next, this will try to extract the `n`th item from the result.  Finally, that result will be assigned to `player_pos`.

If you have not defined a variable named `cave_`, this statement will fail.

It sounds like you are trying to define a sequence of caves and then access an item in that sequence.  One way to do that is as follows:

```
caves = [
    (1,4,0,0),
    (2,11,2,0),
    ...
]

player_pos = caves[player_pos[n]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like a charm on that bug.